# Spark pandas_udf is not faster

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark

I'm facing a heavy data transformation. In a nutshell, I have columns of data, each containing strings which correspond to some ordinals. For example, `HIGH`, `MID` and `LOW`. My objective is to map these strings to integers which will preserve the order. In this case, `LOW -> 0`, `MID -> 1` and `HIGH -> 2`.

Here is a simple function generating such data:

```py
def fresh_df(N=100000, seed=None):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    feat1 = np.random.choice(["HI", "LO", "MID"], size=N)
    feat2 = np.random.choice(["SMALL", "MEDIUM", "LARGE"], size=N)

    pdf = pd.DataFrame({
        "feat1": feat1,
        "feat2": feat2
    })
    return spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

My first approach was:

```py
feat1_dict = {"HI": 1, "MID": 2, "LO": 3}
feat2_dict = {"SMALL": 0, "MEDIUM": 1, "LARGE": 2}

mappings = {
    "feat1": F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in chain(*feat1_dict.items())]),
    "feat2": F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in chain(*feat2_dict.items())])
}

for col in df.columns:
    col_map = mappings[col]
    df = df.withColumn(col+"_mapped", col_map[df[col]])
```

This works as expected but in reality it turns to be slow and I wanted to optimize the process. I read about [`pandas_udf`](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) and it gave me hope. Here is the modified code:

```py
feats_dict = {
    "feat1": feat1_dict,
    "feat2": feat2_dict
}

for col_name in df.columns:
    @F.pandas_udf('integer', F.PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
    def map_map(col):
        return col.map(feats_dict[col_name])
    df = df.withColumn(col_name + "_mapped", map_map(df[col_name]))
```

Alas! When comparing these two versions there was no improvement in terms of execution time. I compared the two on a local instance of Spark (using docker) and on a 5 nodes EMR cluster (with the default configurations).

I created a [notebook](https://gist.github.com/drorata/6f96fccd7735daa4179fa5099c739aaa) where you can see all the code. In general, I used the following imports:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

What am I missing? Why is this process so slow and why there's no improvement when using `pandas_udf`?

Answer (score 2):

Why so slow? Because the Spark runs in JVM and `pyspark` doesn't (because its a python process) and to make it the process possible needs to move all data serializing and deserializing to JVM.

You can map the values with `when` and `otherwise` function and avoid the serialize and deserialize process, increasing the performance.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.shell import spark


def fresh_df(n=100000, seed=None):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    feat1 = np.random.choice(["HI", "LO", "MID"], size=n)
    feat2 = np.random.choice(["SMALL", "MEDIUM", "LARGE"], size=n)

    pdf = pd.DataFrame({
        "feat1": feat1,
        "feat2": feat2
    })
    return spark.createDataFrame(pdf)


df = fresh_df()
df = df.withColumn('feat1_mapped', f
                   .when(df.feat1 == f.lit('HI'), 1)
                   .otherwise(f.when(df.feat1 == f.lit('MID'), 2).otherwise(3)))

df = df.withColumn('feat2_mapped', f
                   .when(df.feat2 == f.lit('SMALL'), 0)
                   .otherwise(f.when(df.feat2 == f.lit('MEDIUM'), 1).otherwise(2)))
df.show(n=20)
```

Output

```
+-----+------+------------+------------+
|feat1| feat2|feat1_mapped|feat2_mapped|
+-----+------+------------+------------+
|   LO| SMALL|           3|           0|
|   LO|MEDIUM|           3|           1|
|  MID|MEDIUM|           2|           1|
|  MID| SMALL|           2|           0|
|  MID| LARGE|           2|           2|
|  MID| SMALL|           2|           0|
|   LO| SMALL|           3|           0|
|  MID| LARGE|           2|           2|
|  MID| LARGE|           2|           2|
|  MID| SMALL|           2|           0|
|  MID|MEDIUM|           2|           1|
|   LO| LARGE|           3|           2|
|   HI|MEDIUM|           1|           1|
|   LO| SMALL|           3|           0|
|   HI|MEDIUM|           1|           1|
|  MID| SMALL|           2|           0|
|  MID|MEDIUM|           2|           1|
|   HI| SMALL|           1|           0|
|   HI| LARGE|           1|           2|
|  MID| LARGE|           2|           2|
+-----+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, this is not going to work in my case. I have 100s of features with 10s of unique values each. I have prepared the maps and I must use these maps (given as JSON where the key is the feature's name and the value is another JSON with the mapping). So, you're saying I have to port my code to Java/Scala?

Comment: Yes, it's strongly recommended (when its possible) implement UDF in Java or Scala to not lose performance

Comment: @Dror Did you solve this?  I have a similar challenge.  I am trying to groupby customers, orders and return rows where my 800 product keywords are columns and the values are prices for those products (quite sparse).  I also am having trouble parallelizing with pandas_udf also.

Comment: Yes, but using an all together different approach.

Comment: @Dror would you mind sharing what that different approach is?

Comment: @Megan, I was lucky enough, and could run it all in memory and use `pandas` ;)

Comment: Dear @Dror, would you please tell how your problem solved? Many thanks.