# pyspark: optimize pandas udf that performs sql query for each row in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark

I am leveraging pyspark and pandas udfs to speedup calculations for a dataframe that contains ~3,500,000 rows. Essentially, I am loading in rows from a table that meet some criteria. Then, I group these by column 'some_col' which roughly should split the data into 4 groups.

I then apply a function that calculates `metric_1` and `metric_2`, where each metric is the number of entries from my table that match some values from the current row. The final calculation is then set in the `final_result` as `(metric_1 / metric_2)`

**Outline of my code**

```
import numpy as np

def calc_metric(arg):
    query = """
        select some_id
            from table
            where some_col = {arg}
    """.format(arg)

    con = # sql connection initialization (not important)

    df = pd.read_sql(con=con, sql=query)

    return

def calculate_metric(df):
    df[metric_1] = df.apply(calc_metric, args=('A'), axis=1)
    df[metric_2] = df.apply(calc_metric, args=('B'), axis=1)
    df[final_metric] = np.where(df[metric_2] != 0,  
            str(float((df[metric_1] / df[metric_2]))), str(float(0)))
    return

@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def calc_metric(df):
    df = calculate_metric(df)
    return df

df = df.groupBy('chosen_groupby_col').apply(calc_metric)
```

This whole process seems to be really slow when I run it locally for one row. I understand that by default apache spark sets `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=200`, and I've noticed when the last task (that actually performs these operations) gets ran, its REALLY slow.

Is this because I am executing a sql query per row? [Or is serializing between Spark JVM and `pyspark` still taking a long time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930974/spark-pandas-udf-is-not-faster) Is there a more optimal way to do this where less data is shuffled and this runs really quick. This will eventually be ran in an aws emr cluster. I've read a lot of posts about how `pandas_udf` GROUPED_MAP functions are supposed to be fast, but this is so slow...

**Edit 1: Broadcasting SQL Connection**
Got an error when I try to broadcast the sql connection:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/megan/apache-spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 113, in dump
    pickle.dump(value, f, 2)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/megan/apache-spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 113, in dump
TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not even be executing a SQL query per row but also opening two  new connections every time. So the part that you leave out saying `not important` is probably the most important part. You might try [broadcasting](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-broadcast.html) the connection.

Comment: thank you I will try that! I believe I tried this before and got an error however when trying to broadcast the sql connection
EDIT: tried it, got this error: `TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects`

Comment: also tried creating `sql_con` from `calculate_metric()` and speed did not improve